# Why is $0 = f(r) = f(x+h) = f(x) + h \cdot f'(x) + O(h^2)$ true?

Tags: calculus

Let $r$ be a zero of $f$ and $x$ be an approximation of $r$. Then why is it true by the Taylor theorem that if $f''$ exists and is continous, then $0 = f(r) = f(x+h) = f(x) + h \cdot f'(x) + O(h^2)$ where $h = r - x$?

It was used/stated in the context of the Newton's method as seen here:
[image]

(Numerical analysis mathematics of scientific computing by Kincaid, David Ronald Cheney, Elliott Ward)

Comment: well we are given that the second derivative is continuous then only the first order approximation can be used as differentiability of the $2^{nd}$  order derivative is not known

Comment: Do you know what the Taylor theorem says ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes :)

Comment: @AdityaGarg but then where does the asymptotic function $O(h^2)$ come from?

Comment: well the n-th order Taylor's approximation of a function say $F(x)$ is some $f_n (x) + O(x^{n+1})$ where the latter is the error or the remainder term ; ain't it ??

Comment: the author considers the contribution of all the higher order terms as $O(h^2)$

Comment: @AdityaGarg: there are no high order terms when you limit the development to the first order.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The thing is that when I look at the definition of Taylor's theorem(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem), it seems to me that the terms are always increasing - by a power of 1. Then I do not understand how you can bound the remaining terms after n=2 to $O(h^2)$

Comment: @noflow: apply the formula with $k=1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Okay I actually see the *first terms* by putting k=1. But I still do not understand how/why you use $O(h^2)$ for the rest - why $h^2$?

Comment: As $f''$ exists, $f(x)=f(0)+hf'(0)+\frac{h^2}2f''(0)+O(h^2)$.